# How to generate async method with svcutil?

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, svcutil.exe, service-operations

Is it possible generate async `ServiceOperation` only for one method by svcutil?

I know I can add `/async` parameter but then it generates all methods in async pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible. Svcutil can't generate partial asynchronous proxies.

[Source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/b269a5cb-fa2d-4a76-afc6-240975a1fdde)

Answer (score 4):

/async option allows you to generate both synchronous and asynchronous method signatures. Default: generate only synchronous method signatures. There is no possablilty to specify particular contract. But [this](http://devlicio.us/blogs/krzysztof_kozmic/archive/2009/08/09/making-asynchronous-wcf-calls-without-svcutil.aspx) may be helpful for you

Comment: I don't see any help under this url. Could you write something more?

Comment: @Saint article under link shows how to call WCF asynchronously without proxy generation

Comment: Note that as of Visual Studio 2012, the default behavior for svcutil appears now to generate both sync and async method signatures. /syncOnly will revert this back to the 'old default'... That wasted three hours of my life this morning.

Comment: "this" link is dead. 503.